UEFI driver doesn't show "Hello World" in EFI Shell on boot
I made this UEFI driver with EDK2. It prints "Hello, World!" and pauses the Shell for 60 seconds. When I load the driver in EFI Shell manually it works perfectly. I then proceeded to pack the .efi as .ffs using this. I added the driver to my BIOS so it autostarts every boot. The driver does pause the boot process for 60 seconds. But there is no picture, my monitor is black during the 60 seconds.
This is my source:
HelloWorld.c:
#include <Uefi.h>
#include <Library/UefiLib.h>
#include <Library/UefiBootServicesTableLib.h>

EFI_STATUS
EFIAPI
UefiMain(EFI_HANDLE ImageHandle, EFI_SYSTEM_TABLE *SystemTable) {
    Print(L"Hello, World!\n");

    gBS->Stall(60000000);

    return EFI_SUCCESS;
}

HelloWorld.inf:
[Defines]
    INF_VERSION = 0x00010006
    BASE_NAME = HelloWorld
    FILE_GUID = 77737B1F-8752-4B9A-BACB-921932118B5B
    MODULE_TYPE = UEFI_DRIVER
    VERSION_STRING = 0.1
    ENTRY_POINT = UefiMain

[Sources]
    HelloWorld.c

[Packages]
    MdePkg/MdePkg.dec

[LibraryClasses]
    UefiDriverEntryPoint
    UefiLib
    UefiBootServicesTableLib

HelloWorldPkg.dsc:
[Defines]
    PLATFORM_NAME = HelloWorldPkg
    PLATFORM_GUID = B68EEAF1-9723-46CB-A5C4-384826F77110
    PLATFORM_VERSION = 0.1
    DSC_SPECIFICATION = 0x00010005
    SUPPORTED_ARCHITECTURES = X64
    BUILD_TARGETS = DEBUG|RELEASE

[LibraryClasses]
    UefiLib|MdePkg/Library/UefiLib/UefiLib.inf
    UefiDriverEntryPoint|MdePkg/Library/UefiDriverEntryPoint/UefiDriverEntryPoint.inf
    PrintLib|MdePkg/Library/BasePrintLib/BasePrintLib.inf
    PcdLib|MdePkg/Library/BasePcdLibNull/BasePcdLibNull.inf
    MemoryAllocationLib|MdePkg/Library/UefiMemoryAllocationLib/UefiMemoryAllocationLib.inf
    DebugLib|MdePkg/Library/UefiDebugLibConOut/UefiDebugLibConOut.inf
    BaseMemoryLib|MdePkg/Library/BaseMemoryLib/BaseMemoryLib.inf
    BaseLib|MdePkg/Library/BaseLib/BaseLib.inf
    UefiBootServicesTableLib|MdePkg/Library/UefiBootServicesTableLib/UefiBootServicesTableLib.inf
    DevicePathLib|MdePkg/Library/UefiDevicePathLib/UefiDevicePathLib.inf
    UefiRuntimeServicesTableLib|MdePkg/Library/UefiRuntimeServicesTableLib/UefiRuntimeServicesTableLib.inf
    RegisterFilterLib|MdePkg/Library/RegisterFilterLibNull/RegisterFilterLibNull.inf
    DebugPrintErrorLevelLib|MdePkg/Library/BaseDebugPrintErrorLevelLib/BaseDebugPrintErrorLevelLib.inf

[Components]
    HelloWorldPkg/HelloWorld.inf

What am I doing wrong? I want to see the "Hello, World!" printed.

Have you configured the dependency section to make sure your driver is loaded after the console driver?

No I didn't. How would I do that?

Maybe one of the tools you used can add this section. If not wait for the protocol to become available, using RegisterProtocolNotify.

I'm really new to EDK2 so I don't know how I would do that? Do you have some source code for me that I could use? The tools I used won't let me add that.

You can define a depex section in your inf file.

What do I put in the Depex section? How would I add the console driver?

The guid of the EFI_SIMPLE_TEXT_OUTPUT_PROTOCOL. Or you wait for the protocol (RegisterProtocolNotify) and leave the depex section empty.
